# Letter by letter uncovering animation effect?

Tags: beamer, animations

I need an appearing effect for text like the one (in javascript) here http://jsfiddle.net/VZvK7/.

However I don't know how to insert js code into LaTeX (apart from using the AcroTeX Bundle) and that would also force me to use Acrobat Reader, so I'd like to implement a similar effect in Beamer. Is it possible?

(of course I would love to see alternative approaches to this)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic idea is to put each letter into a single slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %for justification

\newcommand{\comma}{,}

\newcommand{\myduration}[1]{%
    \foreach \l in {#1}{%
        \transduration<\l>{.05}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\anitext}[2]{%
    \myduration{#1}%
    \foreach \i in {#2}{%
        \temporal<+>{}{\Large\bfseries \vphantom{Mpgjy}\i}{\vphantom{Mpgjy}\i}%        %the phantom removes the bumping
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\justifying
\pause

\anitext{2,...,122}{%
L,o,r,e,m,\space,i,p,s,u,m,\space,d,o,l,o,r,\space,s,i,t,\space,a,m,e,t\comma,\space,c,o,n,s,e,c,t,e,t,u,r,\space,a,d,i,p,i,s,c,i,n,g,\space,e,l,i,t\comma,\space,s,e,d,\space,d,o,\space,e,i,u,s,m,o,d,\space,t,e,m,p,o,r,\space,i,n,c,i,d,i,d,u,n,t,\space,u,t,\space,l,a,b,o,r,e,\space,e,t,\space,d,o,l,o,r,e,\space,m,a,g,n,a,\space,a,l,i,q,u,a.
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I used:

1. `\comma`: a macro for having commas in text without messing up the loop
2. `\myduration`: a macro that sets a `\transduration` effect of .05 seconds. For each letter.
3. `\anitext`: a macro for setting the animation effect using Beamer `\temporal` internally, in the example the text appears as bold and `\Large` and then goes back to normal.

Of course the text to be animated needs to be pre-processed so that each letter is followed by a comma. To do that I put the text to be animated into a separate file and used:

```
cat <finename> | fold -w1 | paste -sd+, -
```

Also, each space needs to be replaced by a `\space` macro (I did it via search&replace).

The first argument of the `\anitext` macro is equal to the number of characters in the original text (without the commas). It is also possible to add a comma after each couple of characterd (with `fold -w2`) but then the animation is less fluid.

[image]

In the MwE the animated text starts at slide number 2, so that the user can advance to slide number 2 when he wants to start the animation and then admire the fake animation :)

I used this also with longer text, up to 450 characters, and apart from the ridiculous number of slides of the resulting PDF, it works fine.

Comment: Effects like this are easy to get with common presentation programs (which I wouldn't mention the name of). They are annoying, to say the least.

Comment: @egreg I think I may have an idea which program you are referring to ;). Anyway, in general I agree (I wouldn't use this into some serious-professional-whatever presentation - if not for pissing off the public), but then, there are more use cases in heaven and earth than are dreamt in your philosophy, as the Poet famously said :)

Comment: Is there some way to do this more "automatic" using luatex?