# how to simulate a Beamer-written slide as if it was done on a blackboard

Tags: beamer, blackboard

Sometime ago, somebody asked a question concerning the simulation of a blackboard presentation written with Beamer. The question had several parts, and I am also interested in one of them, the most difficult one: how to provide the content as if someone was writing on the blackboard, that is, "character by character" (with obviously some control on the speed of the display). That is, imagine a student following a course by looking at home at some slides. I would like that as it clicks on a sort of "play" button, the "virtual piece of chalk writes" a new sentence in the slide, or some block of text. Ideally, this should also happen with the math formulas. At the end, a sound track can be added to complete the simulated teacher. It's important that the material is presented slowly, as in a real blackboard-based lesson, since this gives more time to the student to understand, even if she reads at home.

I think that if there is an easy solution, it concerns the capabilities of some pdf reader, plus a package allowing the author to control this displaying style.

Comment: It is a very very very bad way of animation. Try it on windows movie maker with simple text. It's gets extremely tiring and boring to watch things popping up one by one. Mainly because we don't follow characters we take snapshots of our visual area when we are following.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your question. It makes it much easier for to help when you provide compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A link to the question you are referring to would also save people having to find the needle in the haystack. Agree with @percusse about the animation. Why can't the student just click through the slides one by one, reading them at their own pace?

Comment: you can take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204522/letter-by-letter-uncovering-animation-effect

Comment: Thanks. Concerning the first answer (of percusse), I understand, but the final goal I've been requested for is to have slides where a human voice speaks "giving the lesson". For that reason, the text is supposed to appear slowly, not instantaneously. With usual office-like tools it's easy to do, but not with TeX. Obviously, the user should be able to silent the voice and display the slides normally, that is, instantaneously, if she wishes.